# `+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError). Lucky_seven?(numbers)

Tags: ruby, typeerror, fixnum

I have run in to a slight hiccup.  I'm sure it's simple but for the life of me can't figure it out.

The function of the method is simple, given an array of "numbers", return true if any 3 consecutive numbers add up to 7, else false.

My code below satisfies the first condition in full, as in any qualifying set of numbers will return true.  My problem is that when an array of numbers do not meet the parameters set in the code, instead of false, I get an error of `+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError), any feed back is helpful.  Thanks in advance.  Please see code below: * is the problem line.

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
i = 0
while i < numbers.length 
each_number = numbers[i]
next_number = numbers[i+1]
third_number = numbers[i+2]
 **if  (each_number + next_number + third_number) == 7**
           return true
 end

    i += 1
end
end
```

Comment: What lang is this anyway? You might want to add a tag...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `numbers[i+2]` . But what happens when `i` reaches the last element in numbers?  Try

```
while i < (numbers.length-2)
```

What basically is happening, is that you are accessing an element out of bounds. Also, you should probably put a `return false` statement after the loop.

Comment: Wow, I spent a lot of time researching prior to posting this ?  I had a pretty good idea that it was going to be simple, but now I will never ever forget about mistakenly accessing elements outside the array.  Given the -2 the loop will finish when there are 2 numbers left inside the array, thus removing the typeerror I was receiving.  Also placed the return false right before ending the method, and worked like a charm.  Thanks for your time and feedback.

Comment: @k.parekh if this solved your problem, how about accepting and/or upvoting this answer? ;)

Comment: It's bugs like this that demonstrate why you should use `Enumerable` methods instead of implementing loops yourself: `def lucky_sevens?(numbers) numbers.each_cons(3).any? {|triple| triple.reduce(:+) == 7 } end` See? No loops, no indices to keep track of, it's simply pretty much impossible to get wrong! There is a general rule of thumb in Ruby: if you use a loop, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you very much for the advice! That looks really nice I must say. But probably you should be telling this to OP rather than to me. As you probably can tell from the comment I made on his question, I don't know ruby at all.

Comment: @dingalapadum, hey I already up voted you, but unfortunately my votes cannot be seen publicly, until I accumulate 15 myself.  I put it the first day you posted this.  Also see the accepted answer below.

Comment: @JörgWMittag , your advice is much appreciated, but I am not dabbling in these more advanced methods as I am not comfortable handling them as of this moment.  I am currently working on my fundamental concepts for ruby, and one day will be much more comfortable using the more complex methods.  Looking fwd to it.  Thanks for the example though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the advice above, I made 2 simple changes.  Here is the working version.

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
    i = 0
    while i < (numbers.length - 2) 
    each_number = numbers[i]
    next_number = numbers[i+1]
    third_number = numbers[i+2]
        if(each_number + next_number + third_number) == 7
        return true
        end
    i += 1
    end
return false
end
```